# Strange class template specialization

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class template

```
template <class T>
class A
{
};
```

and very strange specialization

```
template <>
class A<class T*> : private A<void *>
{
};
```

Can anybody explain the meaning of this construction ?

Comment: It would seem that the specialization maps any instantiations with pointer type to the `void*` case, i.e. the template shall treat all pointer types equally.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be correct. `template <>` would imply there are no parameters to the specialization, but `T` is clearly intended to be one.

Comment: @n.m. It's a spezialisation for a `class T;`

Comment: @hansmaad the language rules seem to say so, but the intent of the programmer is probably different, along the lines of rodrigo's answer.

Comment: Another idiom with similar interesting properties is the "Curiously Recurring Template Pattern". This can be very useful for defining type strong, but shared operator overloads and similar constructs where you cannot or do not want virtual methods.

Answer (score 4):

The obfuscation declares a class T and specialize the template for T*

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class A
{
    public:
    static void f() { std::cout << "Template" << '\n'; }
};

// Declare a class T and specialize the template for T*
template <>
class A<class T*> : private A<void *>
{
    public:
    static void f() { std::cout << "Specialization" << '\n'; }
};

class T {};

int main()
{
    // Template
    A<int*>::f();
    // Specialization
    A<T*>::f();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that the intended code would be:

```
template <class T>
class A<T *> : public A<void*>
{
};
```

That is a partial specialization that will be used for any pointer type, instead of the generic one. That is, any time `A` is instantiated using a pointer type, it will use this declearation instead of the generic one.

Naturally you need to instantiate, or otherwise spezialize the `A<void*>`, **before** this declaration, or else you will have an infinite recursion:

```
template class A<void*>;
```

This is a somewhat common idiom to force the compiler to reuse code. That is, you know that every instance of `A<T*>` is basically the same, as all pointers will behave identically under the hood. So you provide the full instantiation of `A<void*>` and then any other `A<T*>` inherits from it, doing the casts inline where needed.

Since `A<T*>` inherits from `A<void*>` it does not need to provide the bulk of the class code in its instantiation. Smaller code will hopefully will yield better performance.

Full example ahead, untested:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
  public:
    A()
    :m_data(0)
    {}
    void set(T x)
    { m_data = x; }
    T get()
    { return m_data; }
    //here there will be more complex operations
  private:
    T m_data;
    //and a lot of data depending on T
};

template class A<void*>; //splicit instantiation

template <typename T>
class A<T*> : public A<void*>
{
  private:
    typedef A<void*> base_type;
  public:
    //only the public, and maybe protected, functions are needed
    //but the implementation is one-line each
    void set(T *x)
    { base_type::set(x); }
    T *get()
    { return static_cast<T*>(base_type::get()); }
};
```